# How to destroy websockets on page reload in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket

I have an app with 3 WebSockets. IE has a limit of 6 by default, so if the page is reloaded 3 times it refuses to connect. The problem is only with IE. Connections are closed fine serverside.
ANY help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [WebSocket.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close) method to close the connection, it will closes the WebSocket connection or connection attempt, if any. If the connection is already CLOSED, this method does nothing.